# tikz - draw line over listings

Tags: tikz-pgf, listings

I wish to draw over listings with lines. but below sample output into 2 different page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=10mm,right=2mm,top=2mm,bottom=2mm,paperwidth=12cm,paperheight=4cm,layoutwidth=12cm,layoutheight=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzmarklibrary{listings}
\definecolor{back-color}{rgb}{0.1686, 0.1686, 0.1686}
\definecolor{string-color}{rgb}{0.3333, 0.5254, 0.345}
\definecolor{key-color}{rgb}{0.8, 0.47, 0.196}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    language = C++,
    basicstyle = {\ttfamily },
    backgroundcolor = {},
    stringstyle = {\color{string-color}},
    morekeywords = {iostream},
    keywordstyle = {\color{key-color}},
    frame=Trbl,numbers=left,
}
\makeatletter
\global\lst@linemarktrue
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle,name=lst1]
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int x = 2;
//comment
for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
    cout << "stand_alone_complex" << endl;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\tikzset{dot/.style={circle,fill=red,minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0}}
\foreach \i in {1,...,7} {
    \coordinate (PS\i) at (pic cs:line-lst1-\i-start);
    \coordinate (PE\i) at (pic cs:line-lst1-\i-end);
    \draw (PS\i) -- (PE\i);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

Page 0:

[image]

Page 1:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly. If you put the `tikzpicture` prior to the `lstlisting` environment (such that it is on the same page) the output becomes interleaved:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=10mm,right=2mm,top=2mm,bottom=2mm,paperwidth=12cm,paperheight=4cm,layoutwidth=12cm,layoutheight=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzmarklibrary{listings}
\definecolor{back-color}{rgb}{0.1686, 0.1686, 0.1686}
\definecolor{string-color}{rgb}{0.3333, 0.5254, 0.345}
\definecolor{key-color}{rgb}{0.8, 0.47, 0.196}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    language = C++,
    basicstyle = {\ttfamily },
    backgroundcolor = {},
    stringstyle = {\color{string-color}},
    morekeywords = {iostream},
    keywordstyle = {\color{key-color}},
    frame=Trbl,numbers=left,
}
\makeatletter
\global\lst@linemarktrue
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\tikzset{dot/.style={circle,fill=red,minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0}}
\foreach \i in {1,...,7} {
    \coordinate (PS\i) at (pic cs:line-lst1-\i-start);
    \coordinate (PE\i) at (pic cs:line-lst1-\i-end);
    \draw (PS\i) -- (PE\i);
}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle,name=lst1]
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int x = 2;
//comment
for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
    cout << "stand_alone_complex" << endl;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that now the `lstlisting` does start a new paragraph and introduces some vertical white space before it, shifting some of it onto the next page. You could either try to revert this space using some `\vspace`, or if you can guarantee that it'll fit on one page, you could just `\hbox` it:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=10mm,right=2mm,top=2mm,bottom=2mm,paperwidth=12cm,paperheight=4cm,layoutwidth=12cm,layoutheight=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzmarklibrary{listings}
\definecolor{back-color}{rgb}{0.1686, 0.1686, 0.1686}
\definecolor{string-color}{rgb}{0.3333, 0.5254, 0.345}
\definecolor{key-color}{rgb}{0.8, 0.47, 0.196}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    language = C++,
    basicstyle = {\ttfamily },
    backgroundcolor = {},
    stringstyle = {\color{string-color}},
    morekeywords = {iostream},
    keywordstyle = {\color{key-color}},
    frame=Trbl,numbers=left,
}
\makeatletter
\global\lst@linemarktrue
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\hbox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\tikzset{dot/.style={circle,fill=red,minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0}}
\foreach \i in {1,...,7} {
    \coordinate (PS\i) at (pic cs:line-lst1-\i-start);
    \coordinate (PE\i) at (pic cs:line-lst1-\i-end);
    \draw (PS\i) -- (PE\i);
}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle,name=lst1]
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int x = 2;
//comment
for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
    cout << "stand_alone_complex" << endl;
}
\end{lstlisting}
}%
\end{document}
```

[image]